# improve quality of recorded video using Red5 media server and oflaDemo app

Tags: apache-flex, video, actionscript, record, red5

what i do now is:

```
cam = Camera.getCamera();   // Get default camera. 
mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();   // Get the microphone
cam.setMode(800, 600, 25);
cam.setQuality(0,90);
videoDisplay.attachCamera(cam);
```

and when the user clicks a button to record i do the following:

```
private function netStatusHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void  {    
            var code:String = e.info.code;              

            Alert.show("code = " + code);   
            if(code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success"){  //in case of recording...

                ns = new NetStream(nc); 
                ns.attachCamera(cam);
                ns.attachAudio(mic);

                ns.publish( "file1", "record" );

            }    
            else{    
                trace(code);   
            }  
        }

        private function start_rec():void{
            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo");
            nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHandler);
        }
```

but the quality of the recording is awful... i follow the same code as above to play the video instead of ns.publish i do ns.play() and the video shown is not as expected although when i ns.play() the ready made flv videos used as samples in red5 they play perfect..there is something wrong with the way i record? with the camera? whats going wrong? any idea??

The code to play the video is:

```
                     var nsClient:Object = {};
            nsClient.onMetaData = ns_onMetaData;

            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);
            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.client = nsClient;

            video = new Video(myVid.width,myVid.height);
            video.attachNetStream(ns);
            video.smoothing=true;
            myVid.addChild(video);

            ns.play("http://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/recordings/file1.flv");`
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
camera = Camera.getCamera();
mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
mic.setLoopBack(false); 
mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
camera.setMode(640,480,30);
camera.setQuality(65536,90);
```

in `camera.setQuality(65536,90);` U can do 100 for best Quality, However it is your choice. Hopefully with these changes, ur quality will be improved very much. Also the quality depends on your webcam too.

Comment: Ok the video is perfect when i see it while i record but when it is stored and i try to play it its awful!i dont know what i do wrong...at first it does not play all the video i record but a little part of it and things move like robots not physically as recorded... see the edit above to see what i do to play the video...

Comment: I am using two different webcams with above settings. The result depends on webcam.

Comment: Just increase setQuality to (65536,100) and buy a good webcam. More i do not know

Comment: Also in camera.setMode(640,480,30) .. here 640  by 480 is the pixels definition increase them for better pixel resolution and 30 is the frame rate per second.. 15 is default for live streaming. But mainly it depends upon your webcam and pixel resolution.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but the problem is that despite i see a very good video while displaying it when i record it through red5 the recorded video is not like the one i see at display what's going on?

Comment: Is there a distortion in it Or are u saying the pixel quality is not good.?
have u tried using a different webcam.

Comment: yes i have tried a different webcam with hd support..the problem is at the oflaDemo app of RED5 which records the video..Do you know any settings i can make to it in order to achieve better recording quality?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the bandwidth. Try to install a bandwidth limiter and then try the recording. You will have a very bad palyback.
If you have a high speed connection then everything will be fine.
If you are using RTMP protocol then it means that everything should be real time. So if the bandwidth is low frames will be dropped.